# How do construct id/parentIds with a recursive function

Tags: arrays

I am trying to build data for a devexpress tree grid using a id/parentId relationship. The id needs to include the complete parent path which will be the parentId, that parentId, that parentId, etc...

So if you look at this screenshot.
[image: SCREENSHOT]

the result I am looking for needs to look like this.

```
[
  {
    id: "EOG",
    parentId: null,
  },
  {
    id: "EOG~division_name~Midland",
    parentId: "EOG",
  },
  {
    id: "EOG~division_name~Midland~entity_color~Blue",
    parentId: "EOG~division_name~Midland",
  },
  {
    id: "EOG~division_name~Midland~entity_color~Blue~area~Area 2",
    parentId: "EOG~division_name~Midland~entity_color~Blue",
  },
  {
    id: "EOG~division_name~Midland~entity_color~Blue~area~Area 1",
    parentId: "EOG~division_name~Midland~entity_color~Blue",
  },
  {
    id: "EOG~division_name~Midland~entity_color~Blue~area~UNKNOWN",
    parentId: "EOG~division_name~Midland~entity_color~Blue",
  },
];
```

It is 0-N hierarchy setup.
You can see what hierarchy is currently selected

> Division / Entity Color / Area

and I need a recursive function to build the ids/parentIds.
Here is the JSON from the API.

```
[
  {
    "id": "EOG",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "CORPUS CHRISTI",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "CHINA",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "DENVER",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "HEADQUARTERS",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "MIDLAND",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "BLUE",
    "level": "2",
    "memSqlColumnName": "entity_color",
    "parentId": "MIDLAND",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "division_name"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 2",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 1",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNKNOWN",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 7",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "RED HILLS",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "RED HILLS NORTH",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "BETA",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ZENA WEST",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "STATELINE",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "K-BAR CORRIDOR",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "NORTH DJ",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 5",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "BAKKEN LITE",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "KBAR",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "NORTH POWDER",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "CORE",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "SOUTH POWDER",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 9",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "POWDER RIVER",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "SPR OFF-CORRIDOR",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ANTELOPE",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "PEGASUS",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "SOLD",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "WEST",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ZENA",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "CORRIDOR A",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ATHENA",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "0",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 2",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ZENA EAST",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "IMPOSSIBLE",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "SDJ",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 3",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 3",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 1",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 8",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "SOUTH DJ",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "NPR CORRIDOR",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "0",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "HOBBS",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ALPHA",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "KING RANCH",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNDAUNTED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "RED HILLS SOUTH",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "HERCULES",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ROSS DRAW",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 1",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ROSS",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "DELAWARE BASIN",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "WEST",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 1",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 6",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "DELAWARE BASIN",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "CENTRAL",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "UNASSIGNED",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "BAKKEN",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "CONAN",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 1",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 1",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "SPR CORRIDOR",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "ELM COULEE",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "CARLSBAD",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "K-BAR",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "AREA 4",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "NPR OFF-CORRIDOR",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "EAST",
    "level": "3",
    "memSqlColumnName": "area",
    "parentId": "BLUE",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "entity_color"
  },
  {
    "id": "BLACK",
    "level": "2",
    "memSqlColumnName": "entity_color",
    "parentId": "MIDLAND",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "division_name"
  },
  {
    "id": "GREEN",
    "level": "2",
    "memSqlColumnName": "entity_color",
    "parentId": "MIDLAND",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "division_name"
  },
  {
    "id": "GOLD",
    "level": "2",
    "memSqlColumnName": "entity_color",
    "parentId": "MIDLAND",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": "division_name"
  },
  {
    "id": "TRINIDAD",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "OKLAHOMA CITY",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "INTL OMAN",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "MIDSTREAM",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "SHARED SERVICES",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "ARTESIA",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "SAN ANTONIO",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "INTERNATIONAL HEADQUARTERS",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "INTL NEW VENTURES",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "FORT WORTH",
    "level": "1",
    "memSqlColumnName": "division_name",
    "parentId": "EOG",
    "parentMemSqlColumnName": ""
  }
]
```

I have no problem using any library that could help such as lodash, etc...

Comment: Two problems: 1- Do you actually NEED recursion? If the data would actually contain as many entries as the counts in the screenshot, you would overflow the stack. Honestly, I shy away from recursion in favor of loops for this exact reason. 2- Does your output actually need to have unique ids? The sample data you provided does NOT have a structure that makes this possible. For example, there are 6 identical entries with id `AREA 1` with the same value for everything, including `parentId`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive. They do need to be unique ids. They should all be able to be unique. The parentId should be the entire path of all parent IDs combined. I've done this before but the API changed the way i call data and the return payload is different. It took me a while to figure it out the last time though

Comment: Well, that's definitely not possible with the data above. There are a lot of identical entries in the source data, so there will be an equal number of identical entries in the output. At first I thought perhaps the ordering would help, but ALL of the `level 3` entries come after `EOG -> MIDLAND -> BLUE` but before the next `level 2`. There is no way to differentiate them.

Comment: I hope my answer help, but I wouldn't award the bounty just yet. Maybe someone else comes up with a more performant solution (a crazy oneliner code perhaps LOL)

Comment: @EricHaynes I’m trying to understand the stack overflow comment—the recursion is for finding the location in the tree which is just a few levels deep.

Comment: @DaveNewton It depends how you implement it. The source data is a flat array, so the typical form of recursion is to process the head, then recurse with the rest of the list, collecting the hierarchy along the way. With 182,000 values, that would overflow the stack. If (and only if), this list were sorted such that parents always exist immediately before children (i.e. all of the `level 2` for a `level 1` immediately follow that `level 1`), then it would be ok, as you could loop through peers, recurse only when level increases, and return when level decreases.

Comment: @EricHaynes I don’t think there was any implication the *array* would be processed recursively; the OP states “I need a recursive function to build the ids/parentIds”, which is a perfectly reasonable use of recursion (although a wee array like this also shouldn’t cause an SOE even if it was).

Comment: Again, recursion would only work if you were able to have a reference to a parent and all of its children at the same time. That way, you could `recurse(parentId, children)` and build all of the children that way. If the data is already sorted that way, then sure, recursion would work.

If the data is NOT sorted that way, you would first have to reduce the entire list in a non-recursive fashion to build that hierarchy. You could just build the result during the sort, so it would be pointless to do one then the other.

And 182,499 values as shown in the screenshot would absolutely SOE.

Comment: It's a moot point here either way. 26/95 (~27%) of the entries are not uniquely identifiable no matter which strategy you choose. It's not solvable as described. You'll feed 95 entries in and get 76 out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every item, you need to recursively look for the parent and build the path in the process. In my solution, I created maps to make the process easier.

- the first iteration is to normalize the data
- the second is to build the paths for each item
- the third is to create the new array with the paths as id and parentId

Not sure if my algorithm is the most performant, but I hope it helps you.

```js
// utility function to create ids
const buildId = (item) =>
  item.memSqlColumnName ? `${item.memSqlColumnName}~${item.id}` : item.id;

const buildIds = (data) => {
  // normalize data for easy access
  const dataMap = data.reduce(
    (acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [buildId(item)]: item }),
    {}
  );

  // create map with paths for each item
  const pathsMap = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let id = buildId(item);
    let currentItem = item;
    let parentKey = null;
    while (currentItem.parentId) {
      parentKey = currentItem.parentMemSqlColumnName
        ? `${currentItem.parentMemSqlColumnName}~${currentItem.parentId}`
        : currentItem.parentId;
      id = `${parentKey}~${id}`;
      currentItem = dataMap[parentKey];
    }
    return {
      ...acc,
      [item.id]: {
        path: id,
      },
    };
  }, {});

  // create arrays with paths for item and parent
  const ids = data.map((item) => {
    return {
      id: pathsMap[item.id].path,
      parentId: item.parentId && pathsMap[item.parentId].path,
    };
  });

  return ids;
};

const data = [
  {
    id: "EOG",
    parentId: null,
  },
  {
    id: "CORPUS CHRISTI",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "CHINA",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "DENVER",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "HEADQUARTERS",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "MIDLAND",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "BLUE",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 2",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNKNOWN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 7",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "RED HILLS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "RED HILLS NORTH",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BETA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ZENA WEST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "STATELINE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "K-BAR CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NORTH DJ",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 5",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BAKKEN LITE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "KBAR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NORTH POWDER",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CORE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SOUTH POWDER",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 9",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "POWDER RIVER",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SPR OFF-CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ANTELOPE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "PEGASUS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SOLD",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "WEST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ZENA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CORRIDOR A",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ATHENA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "0",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 2",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ZENA EAST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "IMPOSSIBLE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SDJ",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 3",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 3",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 8",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SOUTH DJ",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NPR CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "0",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "HOBBS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ALPHA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "KING RANCH",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNDAUNTED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "RED HILLS SOUTH",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "HERCULES",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ROSS DRAW",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ROSS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "DELAWARE BASIN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "WEST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 6",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "DELAWARE BASIN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CENTRAL",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BAKKEN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CONAN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SPR CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ELM COULEE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CARLSBAD",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "K-BAR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 4",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NPR OFF-CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "EAST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BLACK",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "GREEN",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "GOLD",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "TRINIDAD",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "OKLAHOMA CITY",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "INTL OMAN",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "MIDSTREAM",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "SHARED SERVICES",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "ARTESIA",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "SAN ANTONIO",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "INTERNATIONAL HEADQUARTERS",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "INTL NEW VENTURES",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "FORT WORTH",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
];

console.log(buildIds(data));
```

Comment: seems to work great! there was one issue. the root node EOG was being duplicated so I just removed those with lodash uniqBy. If you want to update for a fix that is cool. if not thanks for your help!!!

Comment: There are these duplicates in the list: `10xEOG~division_name~MIDLAND~entity_color~BLUE~area~UNASSIGNED`
`6xEOG~division_name~MIDLAND~entity_color~BLUE~area~AREA 1`
`2xEOG~division_name~MIDLAND~entity_color~BLUE~area~AREA 2`
`2xEOG~division_name~MIDLAND~entity_color~BLUE~area~WEST`
`2xEOG~division_name~MIDLAND~entity_color~BLUE~area~0`
`2xEOG~division_name~MIDLAND~entity_color~BLUE~area~AREA 3`
`2xEOG~division_name~MIDLAND~entity_color~BLUE~area~DELAWARE BASIN`

Answer (score 1):

#### Key points

1. We can cache the item IDs in a JS object with original IDs mapping to structured IDs.
2. Lucky for us we have `level` key and data is sorted so the parents will be processed before children.

#### Implementation Ideas

So we keep a temporary JS object `idMap` mapping the original item ID to the newly generated item ID for reference by children items later on.

While creating IDs we prepend `memSqlColumnName` value if available seperated by a `~`. And if the item has a parent we grab and prepend the parents ID as well separated by a `~`.

All this can be done efficiently in a single loop.

In case the data turns out to not be sorted by `level`, we can do so ourselves easily with a simple [compare function on `array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#comparefn).

```
// Sort by level, parents before children
items.sort( ( a, b ) => +a.level - b.level )
```

#### Example implementation

```js
/**
 * Formats data
 * @param {array} items
 * @returns {array} Restructured items
 */
function processData(items) {
  const idMap = {}; // IDs cache to get parent IDs

  /** Generates the ID */
  function generateId(item) {
    // Use memSqlColumnName if set
    let newID = item.memSqlColumnName ? `${item.memSqlColumnName}~${item.id}` : item.id;

    if (item.parentId)
      newID = idMap[item.parentId] + '~' + newID; // Prepend parent ID (if we got one).

    return idMap[item.id] = newID; // Return and cache the new ID
  }

  return items
    .map(item => ({
      id: generateId(item), // Generate ID
      parentId: idMap[item.parentId] || null, // Update parent ID from cache
    }));
}

// Data placed in an html script tags for clean code
console.log(processData(window.originalData));
```

```html
<script>
// All data
window.originalData = [
  {
    id: "EOG",
    parentId: null,
  },
  {
    id: "CORPUS CHRISTI",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "CHINA",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "DENVER",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "HEADQUARTERS",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "MIDLAND",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "BLUE",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 2",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNKNOWN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 7",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "RED HILLS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "RED HILLS NORTH",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BETA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ZENA WEST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "STATELINE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "K-BAR CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NORTH DJ",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 5",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BAKKEN LITE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "KBAR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NORTH POWDER",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CORE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SOUTH POWDER",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 9",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "POWDER RIVER",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SPR OFF-CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ANTELOPE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "PEGASUS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SOLD",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "WEST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ZENA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CORRIDOR A",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ATHENA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "0",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 2",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ZENA EAST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "IMPOSSIBLE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SDJ",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 3",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 3",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 8",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SOUTH DJ",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NPR CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "0",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "HOBBS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ALPHA",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "KING RANCH",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNDAUNTED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "RED HILLS SOUTH",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "HERCULES",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ROSS DRAW",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ROSS",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "DELAWARE BASIN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "WEST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 6",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "DELAWARE BASIN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CENTRAL",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "UNASSIGNED",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BAKKEN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CONAN",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 1",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "SPR CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "ELM COULEE",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "CARLSBAD",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "K-BAR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "AREA 4",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "NPR OFF-CORRIDOR",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "EAST",
    level: "3",
    memSqlColumnName: "area",
    parentId: "BLUE",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
  },
  {
    id: "BLACK",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "GREEN",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "GOLD",
    level: "2",
    memSqlColumnName: "entity_color",
    parentId: "MIDLAND",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "division_name",
  },
  {
    id: "TRINIDAD",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "OKLAHOMA CITY",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "INTL OMAN",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "MIDSTREAM",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "SHARED SERVICES",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "ARTESIA",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "SAN ANTONIO",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "INTERNATIONAL HEADQUARTERS",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "INTL NEW VENTURES",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
  {
    id: "FORT WORTH",
    level: "1",
    memSqlColumnName: "division_name",
    parentId: "EOG",
    parentMemSqlColumnName: "",
  },
];
</script>
```